# Performance of Modified Dijkstra's algorithm with Binariy heap as Priority Queue

Tags: algorithms, graphs, algorithm-analysis, asymptotics, performance

we know the performance of Dijkstra's algorithm with binary heap is O(log |V |) for delete_min, O(log |V |) for insert/ decrease_key, so the overall run time is O((|V|+|E|)log|V|).

Now let's modify the Dijkstra to stop once it reaches T (Destination) from S(Start). The given performance is:
[image]

Understand that we don't need to explore the full G in the modified Dijkstra run. 
Can someone explain why it is the diamond shape(the 45 degree rotate of a perfect square)?

What does it means with the **radios** of |m|+|n|, (typo of radius ?)

What is m and n in this case? (m means vertices? n means edges?) seems to me that $(|m|+|n|)^2$ is half of the vertices and edges visited，which is half of the Diamond/Square. Then not sure how is it is computed.

added new pic for the additional questions
[image]

Comment: Please add a url or reference to the original material _in the question_.

Comment: Have you tried running the Dijkstra's algorithm in this situation? Please reach at least 13 nodes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the example, we can assume the start cell $s$ is the origin in a plane consisting of square cells with Descarte coordinates.  That is, $s$ is $(0,0)$. The coordinate of destination cell, $t$ is $(m,n)$. The distance of any two cells is given by [the taxicab geometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxicab_geometry#Formal_definition). That is, the distance between cells $(p_1,p_2)$ and $(q_1,q_2)$ is
$$d((p_1,q_2),(q_1,q_2))=|p_1-p_2|+|q_1-q_1|$$
In particular, $d(s,t)=|m|+|n|$.

At the last step of running Dijkstra's algorithm with source cell $s$ when we visit cell $t$, all cells whose distance to $s$ is smaller than $d(s,t)$ must have been visited. Some of the cells whose distance to $s$ is $d(s,t)$ may have also been visited. If you color all cells that are no more than $d(s,t)$ away from $s$, you will get a diamond shape whose boundary cells $(p,q)$ are given by the following equations.

$$ \begin{align}
p+q = d(s,t)  &\text{ where }p\ge0, q\ge0. \text{ This is the top right segment.}\\
p-q = d(s,t)  &\text{ where }p\ge0, q\le0. \text{ This is the bottom right segment.}\\
-p+q = d(s,t) &\text{ where }p\le0, q\ge0. \text{ This is the top left  segment.}\\
-p-q = d(s,t) &\text{ where }p\le0, q\le0. \text{ This is the bottom left segment.}\\
\end{align}$$

That diameter shape is, in fact, a circular disk with center $(0,0)$ and radius $|m|+|n|$ in the taxicab geometry. Yes, as you pointed out, "radios" should be "radius".

How many cells are there in the diamond shape? The diamond shape is actually a square the length of whose diagonals is $2(|m|+|n|)$. So its area is $(2(|m|+|n|))^2/2=2(|m|+|n|)^2$, which is about the number of cells in the it asymptotically.

---

**Exercise.** The exact number of cells in a disk with radius $r$ in the taxicab geometry is $2r^2+2r+1$. In particular, there are 13 cells in a disk with radius 2.

Comment: Can you please point out why "The diamond shape is actually a square whose diagonal is 2(|m|+|n|)" or is is just the law?  The diagonal of the square is the blue line, correct? Please see the the picture with the blue line.   2(|m|+|n|) seem like some line random as red line.

Comment: Yes, one of the diagonals of the square is the blue segment. The other diagonal is the vertical segment through $s$. It is then law in taxicab geometry. That is, a circular disk with radius $r$ in the taxicab geometry is a square whose diagonals are $2r$ in the usual Euclidean geometry.